# OpenLayers deploy: what libs does selectFeature rely on?

Tags: openlayers-2, performance, select

I am trying to minimize my code by modifying OpenLayers deploy configuration file in order to reduce its `load time`. However, It seems that I can't include all necessary libs that OpenLayers.SelectFeature.Control needs. Here is the config file:

```
    [include]
OpenLayers/Map.js
OpenLayers/Kinetic.js
OpenLayers/Projection.js
OpenLayers/Handler.js
OpenLayers/Control.js
OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Pixel.js
OpenLayers/BaseTypes/LonLat.js
OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds.js
OpenLayers/Layer/SphericalMercator.js
OpenLayers/Layer/XYZ.js
OpenLayers/Layer/WMS.js
OpenLayers/Layer/Vector.js
OpenLayers/Layer/ArcGISCache.js
OpenLayers/Control/TouchNavigation.js
OpenLayers/Control/Geolocate.js
OpenLayers/Control/Attribution.js
OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature.js
OpenLayers/Control/DrawFeature.js
OpenLayers/Control/ModifyFeature.js
OpenLayers/Control/Snapping.js
OpenLayers/Control/Split.js
OpenLayers/Control/Panel.js
OpenLayers/Control/Button.js
OpenLayers/Control/PinchZoom.js
OpenLayers/Feature/Vector.js
OpenLayers/Feature/WFS.js
OpenLayers/Handler/Click.js
OpenLayers/Handler/Feature.js
OpenLayers/Handler/Hover.js
OpenLayers/Handler/Box.js
OpenLayers/Renderer/SVG.js
OpenLayers/Renderer/Canvas.js
OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON.js
OpenLayers/Format/KML.js
OpenLayers/Format/WFS.js
OpenLayers/Format/WFSCapabilities.js
OpenLayers/Format/WFSCapabilities/v1.js
OpenLayers/Format/WFSCapabilities/v1_0_0.js
OpenLayers/Format/WFSCapabilities/v1_1_0.js
OpenLayers/Format/WFSDescribeFeatureType.js
OpenLayers/Format/XML.js
OpenLayers/Request/XMLHttpRequest.js
OpenLayers/Protocol/HTTP.js
OpenLayers/Protocol/WFS.js
OpenLayers/Protocol/WFS/v1.js
OpenLayers/Protocol/WFS/v1_0_0.js
OpenLayers/Protocol/WFS/v1_1_0.js
OpenLayers/Strategy/Fixed.js
OpenLayers/Strategy/BBOX.js
```

When I test selectFeature feature which has a feature info popup in OnSelect, it always tells me following error:

```
cannot call "add" of undefined
```

which I think it points out that in the file of `selectFeature.js`, under "pixelToBounds", the variable "pixel" is undefined, and then I assume it's relevant to the recognition of "evt".

Could somebody give me some hints?

Answer (score 1):

if you check out the code of selectFeature Control, you can see requiring files as following:

```
/**
 * @requires OpenLayers/Control.js
 * @requires OpenLayers/Feature/Vector.js
 * @requires OpenLayers/Handler/Feature.js
 * @requires OpenLayers/Layer/Vector/RootContainer.js
 */
```